# Shift distance of number

Tags: code-golf, bitwise

Given two non-zero 16-bit integers `a` and `b`, decide the smallest number of shift operations needed to turn `a` into `b`. A shift is one of the following (big-endian) operations:

- `shl` (shift left): move all bits to the left, adding a `0x0` bit to the right.
- `shr` (shift right): move all bytes to the right, adding a `0x0` bit to the left.
- `sar` (arithmetic shift right): move all bits to the right, duplicating the leftmost bit.
- `rol` (rotate left): move all bits to the left, replacing the rightmost bit with the leftmost bit.
- `ror` (rotate right): move all bits to the right, replacing the leftmost bit with the rightmost bit.

Or, if the number is expressed in 16-bit big-endian binary x15x14...x1x0, then allowed operations are listed as following:

```
(original)  x15 x14 x13 x12 x11 x10  x9 x8 x7 x6 x5 x4 x3 x2 x1  x0
shl         x14 x13 x12 x11 x10  x9  x8 x7 x6 x5 x4 x3 x2 x1 x0   0
shr           0 x15 x14 x13 x12 x11 x10 x9 x8 x7 x6 x5 x4 x3 x2  x1
sar         x15 x15 x14 x13 x12 x11 x10 x9 x8 x7 x6 x5 x4 x3 x2  x1
rol         x14 x13 x12 x11 x10  x9  x8 x7 x6 x5 x4 x3 x2 x1 x0 x15
ror          x0 x15 x14 x13 x12 x11 x10 x9 x8 x7 x6 x5 x4 x3 x2  x1
```

Test cases:

```
1, 4 => 2 # shl, shl
10, 8 => 4 # shr, shr, shl, shl
1, 65535 => 16 # ror, sar*15
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Can I take the input in binary, padded with zeros to 16 bits?

Comment: @CommandMaster If that's an usual integer expression, I'd say

Comment: Can you clarify the operations and what you mean by rotations please?

Comment: Should we output only the number, or the sequence of operations? Is it guaranteed that there is a solution?

Comment: Can we assume \$a\neq b\$?

Comment: @Arnauld That's reasonable assumption

Comment: @LuisMendo The number is enough. Any nonzero can convert into another any number

Comment: I attempted to add descriptions of the operations; let me know if I messed them up. I may have erred in the interpretation of bits versus bytes, since the example you have appeared to actually be working with nibbles rather than either bits or bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 107 bytes

*-5 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

Expects `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
p=>g=q=>g[g[p]=q]?0:1+g(q,(_=>{for(v in g)[v*2,h=v/2,v<<15|h,v>>15|v*2,v&1<<15|h].map(v=>g[v&65535]=1)})())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3BCoJAEAbge0/hSWZqM9faiHC3B5ElxHQ1zF015lI9u2kdFYYZ@PiZ/55S2mdd5Z7bxt7yoZCDk8rIdlyJSZyWrb6EZ74x0DK4SvUqbAfkVY1nMKF1xEpJu4hRHHPxLhkpNd7Jyed/08EjdUDTQ/KPQuyFlhw/CIhDZpve1nlQWwMFcBwHVzOMlvAwxxDhtBT9lY5tXw)

#### Commented

```javascript
p =>                     // p = initial value
g = q =>                 // q = target value
g[g[p] = q]              // mark p as already found
?                        // if q was found:
  0                      //   stop the recursion
:                        // else:
  1 +                    //   increment the final result
  g(                     //   do a recursive call:
    q,                   //     pass q
    ( _ => {             //     dummy function to process a for
      for(v in g) [      //     for each value v found so far:
        v * 2,           //       compute shl
        h = v / 2,       //       compute shr
        v << 15 | h,     //       compute ror
        v >> 15 | v * 2, //       compute rol
        v & 1 << 15 | h  //       compute sar
      ]                  //
      .map(v =>          //       and for each of them:
        g[v & 65535]     //         keep the 16 lower bits
        = 1              //         and mark the result as found
      )                  //       end of map()
    })()                 //     end of for
  )                      //   end of recursive call
```

Comment: [110 support a=b](https://tio.run/##ZcxBDoIwFATQvQch/2tFqtYYQ@sRPEDTBWIpItIi5Ccm3h1R40Y3M8nLZKqMsi6/nUM/b/zJDoUcglROtmNop4ORrdknOz5z0LLDsbJ5H1/svQOH8TULQFJpmi5ZKWmxZJSmXDxKRkqN/XKK@MfMd@40RRshVsJIjohD7pvO1zauvYMCOMIacfKDCcL2XxHeP@PHEw)

Comment: [107](https://tio.run/##ZcxBDoIwEIXhvadgRWa0IkVrjKH1IKQxBGnBIC1gZqOeHUF3unkv@Rb/Nad8KPra39etu5SjkaOXyspumsxmXstOn@IjX1noGJylehjXAwV1G1jMaJmwStImYZSmXDwrRkpNPzuF/Gs6uuUeaA5SuBdiK7Tk@EJAHAvXDq4po8ZZMMARdoiLH4wRDv@K8ElNjTc)

Comment: "

Given two non-zero 16-bit integer a and b"

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 255 bytes

```python
def f(x,y,i=0):
 while 1:
  for p in product(*[[lambda n:n[1:]+'0',lambda n:n[:-1],lambda n:n[0]+n[:-1],lambda n:n[1:]+n[0],lambda n:n[-1]+n[:-1]]]*i):
   r=x
   for q in p:r=int(q(bin(r)[2:].zfill(16)),2)
   if r==y:return i
  i+=1
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BasMwEETv/oqFHiLZarGSOgSBvsTokMQWWZAlZauQuD/vSiEEQ0@783ZmmTinS/C7ZRlGC5Y9xCxQt1xVcL@gG0HmDWwgiIAeIoXhdk6s7nt3nE7DEbzyvVSm2bQbsULqU5q1bk3zH5ZcOa1ZtrycxtRYegCQfpRRWlyfLRRp9Ild2Qk9I95vlfn6tegck3vOxZYXO9oc1LOiMd3IA2aGjZaVpTABppFSCO4HcIqBUr1EKi8tkwK@Oa/eshVwyPoDVoZ91@06zpc/)

Brute force method (very slow). It goes through every single possibility. The last test case times out on TIO.

Takes in two integers and returns an integer.

---

**Explanation:**

```python
def f(x,y,i=0):                                 # Create a function, f, which takes in x and y. Define i as 0
 while 1:                                       # Forever:
  for p in product(*[...]*i):                   #   Go through every combination of length i. (Five functions have been defined here, each corresponding to one of the shifts/rotations)
   r=x                                          #     Set r to x
   for q in p:r=int(q(bin(r)[2:].zfill(16)),2)  #     Apply each function in p to r
   if r==y:return i                             #     If r equals y, return i (the number of functions we applied)
  i+=1                                          #   Add one to i
from itertools import*                          # Import the itertools library
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 61 bytes

```
≔⟦Ｎ⟧θＮη≔Ｘ⁸¦⁵ζＷ¬№θη«≔ΣＥθ⟦⊗﹪κζ÷κ²⁺＆κζ÷κ²⁺⊗﹪κζ÷κζ⁺×﹪κ²ζ÷κ²⟧θ→»Ｉⅈ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZDPSsNAEIfx2DzF0tMspKAFIdhTbS8VUoJ6EEIO-bPtDm522-xuAhWfxEsPFX0mn8ZdGqWghx7nm29-ML-3z5LnTalysd-_W7MaRV8Xd1OtcS0hXciNNUtbF6wBmoVkSyfBKeNu7t1EdQ5EIbmmIdk53nEUjMBSGZgpKw1sQ8IppeQlGPQ3D7aGON_4TTpXthCsglhVVih49iEuaSHNHFusmCdjBxJhNdyi6VCzqayO4h_vRzwndfdrP2LN9Ik7pv-HZ_7CdzGIVcvg5h7X3LjxNUgadJ_Ocm3gCdyzk4MuSt0X-5EOR60YZoerSxId0Tc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Lots of brute force, so times out for anything interesting.

```
≔⟦Ｎ⟧θ
```

Start with having discovered `a`.

```
Ｎη
```

Input `b`.

```
≔Ｘ⁸¦⁵ζ
```

Precompute `32768`.

```
Ｗ¬№θη«
```

Repeat until `b` is discovered.

```
≔ΣＥθ⟦⊗﹪κζ÷κ²⁺＆κζ÷κ²⁺⊗﹪κζ÷κζ⁺×﹪κ²ζ÷κ²⟧θ
```

Replace each discovered value with the results of its five shifts.

```
→
```

Keep track of the number of shifts taken.

```
»Ｉⅈ
```

Output the required number of shifts.

106 bytes for a less inefficient version that also outputs the list of shifts required:

```
≔Ｘ⁸¦⁵ζ≔Ｅ⊗ζ⟦⟧η⊞υＮＮθＦυＦ¬§ηθＦ⁵«≔§⟦⊗﹪ιζ÷ι²⁺＆ιζ÷ι²⁺⊗﹪ιζ÷ιζ⁺×﹪ι²ζ÷ι²⟧λκＦ¬§ηκ«§≔ηκ⁺§ηι⟦§⪪”&→∧¡?kiNⅉ｜Ｍ”³λ⟧⊞υκ»»§ηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFNawIxFDxvfkXw9AIpqEUQPG3x4kFZaG@yh9WNTTAmaz60bPG3bxO7KUvroZeENzN58@Zlzyuz15Xsutxa8a6g0FdmYE7xjFDckgXq8XXVwFL7nWQ1tIHaluHggS@85eApXqnGu40/7cJzEvBhfQ71QRsMnuD7vdEOcrdSNfsATvGZkJ6YEfyJst4zKbbJeK1rLzWIOBmJlm4pLqJmEZkGoJDewotwV2FZrupv4R9dEv6na/ujfhMnZgfaKXncvKRYBvgYImePsh5j1pCxDzlkeqcBJOKmU/3aSOFgZLm03NjKGC2NNiOKn0n0LOPWsyz9x32AG7qhwgj1e9uLrpuM0bx7usgv) Link is to verbose version of code. Requires `a` and `b` to be different. Explanation:

```
≔Ｘ⁸¦⁵ζ
```

Precompute 32768.

```
≔Ｅ⊗ζ⟦⟧η
```

Start with not having discovered anything.

```
⊞υＮ
```

Start a breadth-first search at `a`.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `b`.

```
ＦυＦ¬§ηθ
```

Loop over the discovered numbers until `b` has been discovered.

```
Ｆ⁵«≔§⟦⊗﹪ιζ÷ι²⁺＆ιζ÷ι²⁺⊗﹪ιζ÷ιζ⁺×﹪ι²ζ÷ι²⟧λκ
```

Loop over the five shifts and compute the current shift's value.

```
Ｆ¬§ηκ«
```

If this value has not yet been discovered, then...

```
§≔ηκ⁺§ηι⟦§⪪”&→∧¡?kiNⅉ｜Ｍ”³λ⟧
```

... record the shifts needed to reach it, and...

```
⊞υκ
```

... add it to the list of discovered values.

```
»»§ηθ
```

Output the shifts needed to reach `b`.